# Best way to show a primefaces p:tooltip on page load

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

I want to open a tooltip when page loads for first time... somehow just like a help guide for first time use opens the page, not waiting for him to hover mouse on the object.

Best approach?
thanks

Comment: Hi, why not opening a simple dialog that contain informations ??? , if no be more specific

Comment: Thanks for your entry but... I can't be more specific. I need to use tooltip, p:tooltip... not Dialog or any other component because they do different things. Thanks.

Comment: Both answers below are valid but the purely PF one does not require an additional component suite (although strongly related). But I personally would think a dialog would attract more focus from the user if you want to show help. More specifically if it is modal, but if you usecase really requires a tooltip, I'd go for the purely PrimeFaces answer.

Comment: Yes, it is good to know I can use pe, which I am not using at all, but I'll try unload in h:body. The reason to use tooltip is to have a sequence of tooltips showing and linked exactly to the input field that has to be entered. That cannot be done with a dialog.

Comment: Correct, but having several of them open is 'chaotic' and when do they close?

Comment: The tooltips are shown using requestContext.execute("PF('" + widgetVar + "').show()"); from the managed bean. Before showing one, I use hide() in previous one. It works perfect. Only one is open at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `onload` attribute in the `body` tag:

```html
<h:body onload="PF('tip1').show();">
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText id="txt" title="Type something into this field"/>
        <p:tooltip for="txt" widgetVar="tip1" value="tooltip text"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrimeFaces Extensions  [Auto Shown tooltip](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/tooltip/autoShownTooltips.jsf)

Download jar file from: [primefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/extensions/primefaces-extensions/6.0.0/primefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar)

namespace:

xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"

usage:

```
<h:panelGrid id="details" columns="2">  
<h:outputLabel value="Tooltip on InputText: "/>  
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="padding: 0 0 3px 0;">  
    <p:inputText id="txt" title="Type something into this field"/>  
    <pe:tooltip for="txt" autoShow="true" widgetVar="tip1"  
                myPosition="left center" atPosition="right center"/>  
</h:panelGroup>
```